# Why does htop start so quickly?

Tags: process, proc, top, c++, htop

I tried to read info about processes from [/proc/](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) just like htop and top do.

It seems like the value for "CPU%" in htop or top is calculated by summing up the values utime and stime in the stat file of a process, repeating that after a certain time, and dividing the difference by the time passed. Since the accuracy usually seems to be 10 ms (getconf CLK_TCK returns 100), I figure you have to wait at least a second to get a three digit accuracy.

However, htop and top show their processes with the "CPU%" values immediately.

Do they use some kind of trick or am I making a mistake here?

My current (C++) implementation which backs up my claim, looks something like this:

```
// acquire initial
std::this_thread::sleep_for(measuringPeriod);
// acquire final

static const long CLK_TCK = sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);
long unsigned int initialTime = initial.utime + initial.stime;
long unsigned int finalTime = final.utime + final.stime;
long unsigned int time = finalTime - initialTime;
double measuringTime = (double)(std::chrono::duration_cast
                                <std::chrono::milliseconds>(measuringPeriod)
                                .count()) / 1000.0; // in seconds
double cpuLoad = (double)time * 100.0 / (double)CLK_TCK
                              / measuringTime; // in percent
```

Comment: `htop` is not the only process in your system that is monitoring this. ;)

Comment: I'm sure it isn't, but do you think htop is acquiring its info from some running system service that I could use similarly? I always thought, all those tools always took that directly from /proc/